# Let A be a vector perpendicular to every vector X. Show that A = 0.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a vector perpendicular to every vector $X$. Show that $A = 0$.

Suppose $A = X$.

$$A \cdot X = 0 \implies  a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 = 0.$$

Since the square of any real number is nonnegative and the only sum of nonnegatve reals that equals $0$ is the sum of $0$s, $a_i^2 = 0$. Then, $a_i = 0$. So, $A = 0$.

How do we prove it for X $ \neq $ A? Or is there a better proof for this statement that doesn't assume the knowledge of matrices and anything even more advanced? Thanks.

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: a1b1+a2b2....+anbn=0. What happens when one of the b_i's becomes twice of what it originally was?

Comment: As a matter of style, "Let $X=A$" is probably stronger than "Suppose $A=X$" - there's no need to consider what happens for other vectors, since $A$ is definitely a vector in the space, and hence "$A\cdot A=0$" is implied by "A is perpendicular to every vector"

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Firstly, take in the place of $x$ the basis vectors $e^j$ with $$e^j_i=\begin{cases}1, & i=j \\0, & i \neq j\end{cases}=(0,0,0,\ldots,0\underbrace{1}_{j-\text{th position}},0,
\ldots,0)$$ Now A is perpendicular to every $e^j$. What does this imply?

Write, subsequently every vector $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ as a linear combination of the $e^j$, that is $$x=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_je^j$$ to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is complete.  There is no need to prove anything for $X\ne A$.  It's not like you were supposed to prove something for all $X$ and only proved it for $X=A$.  Quite the opposite: the hypothesis told you something was true for all $X$, and you only used it for one particular $X$.  That's not incomplete, it's thrifty.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(a_1,a_2,....,a_n)$
and $X = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$

Then $A\cdot X=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+.....a_nx_n = 0$

Now, suppose there is $Y=(2x_1,x_2,x_3,....x_n)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,....x_n)+(x_1,0,0,...0)$

Then $A\cdot Y=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+.....a_nx_n)+(a_1x_1,0,0....,0)=A\cdot X+(a_1x_1,0,...,0)$

i.e. $A\cdot Y=0=0+a_1x_1$

As $x_1$ is arbitrary, we have
$a_1=0$

Similarly show this for other $a_i$'s